# Is there client socket library for micropython (esp32)?

Tags: socket.io, iot, esp32, micropython

I am facing an issue in connecting my ESP-32(in micropython) to my socket server(in nodejs). I have successfully connected to server via browser or flutter but I am unable to connect to it using my esp32.
I am new to micropython , please help me to find the "correct approach" or "some library" so that I can move ahead. I am stuck due to this.
Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

If this is a general question about sockets, you should try usocket documented at https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/usocket.html. The examples below are more or less the same from the usocket docs:

Sockets can be created like this :

```
# TCP socket
s = usocket.socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

# UDP socket
s = usocket.socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
```

After this, you can do s.connect(...), s.send(...), s.write(...), socket.recv(...), s.read(..) etc.

Comment: Thank You for your answer. I will try this. i have gone through the docs but find its difficult to implement . eg  I need to pass query param with socket.  I switched back to ardunioIDE back for now. but i will give some try more in micropython.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you are new to Python socket programming. I would suggest testing some Python code on a computer before trying to implement it on a microcontroller. You can use the libraries (almost) the same way.

Comment: yes , i am new to micropython and infact i am new to python :D .  so you suggest for i need to learn python before learning micropython ?

Comment: Simple answer: Yes